# Any package that would get the lidar and imu and odometery, the occuupancy grid map as an input and get me the location of the robot as an output?

Tags: localization, imu, navigation, lidar, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a total ROS newbie and i am wondering if you could help me finding a package that would get the lidar and imu and odometery and the occuupancy grid map as an input and get me the exact location of the robot as an output?  thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254400/i-am-a-total-ros-newbie-and-i-am-wondering-if-you-could-help-me-finding-a-package-that-would-get-the-lidar-and-imu-and-odometery-and-the-occuupancy-grid-map-as-an-input-and-get-me-the-exact-location-of-the-robot-as-an-output?--thank-you-in-advance./) by [Amr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29331/amr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-08-23**:
Welcome to ROS :) 
In the future dont post the question in your title. The title should be short description of your problem. You can try now to edit your question and change the title. In regards to your question, check amcl localization package as @Subodh Malgonde pointed out in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) does exactly what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 512 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2